# AVPlayer can only play up to 16videos

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer

I have implemented a pager in which each page shows the user a video. Each page has his own AVPlayer instanciated. 
Everything work as expected until the 17th video.

I read a lot regarding this issue. It appears that this is an Apple limitation, where an app is limited to display the player layers.

The solution I tried (several sources says it fixes the issue) is to remove the player layer from its parent and set the player to Nil. So each time a page disappears (didDisappear) I call:

```
// player and playerLayer are init at viewWillAppear().
player?.pause()
player = nil
playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
```

That does not change anything... I am still limited to 16 video plays.

Thus, my question is:

1) Why this behavior? Is it really expected?

2) How do Musical.ly or Snapchat achieve to switch infinitly between videos?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you reuse pages?

Comment: Yes I can. Any suggestion with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code with

```
player?.pause()
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
player = nil
```

setting `nil` item into player will stop playing.

1) Yes, it's expected behavior for AVPlayer. It was designed for video players creation or for displaying ads videos in games, but not for videos walls like has Instagram or similar services.

2) It's simple. They are not using AVPlayer. For your purpose you can use combination of `AVAssetReader` and `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`

Comment: Thks Taras. I will try this. I have had in my mind to use AVAssetReader as well but wanted to understand the situation before going with it.

Comment: Hey Taras. Calling replaceCurrentItem:nil seems to resolve the issue. Thanks! I keep AVPlayer for now for simplicity. I imagine the other solution with AvAssetReader would be better for resources consomption, wouldn't it?